# SMPP GENERIC_nack :message Invalid opensmpp Logica

Tags: java, smpp

I've had developing smpp client...but when it cames to delivery report...it always automatically send generic_nack,,I'm using opensmpp logica, it seem ,it always get invalid pdu from server,, how to disable this generic nack,, or is there any other way to get pdu response from server without automatically send generic nack,, below the tcp dump

[image: tcpdump generic_nack]

Thank's

Regards

Danz

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable this (ESME_RINVMSGLEN/0x00000001) or any generic nack; it's the SMSC that's sending it.

You can try to create a scenario so that the SMCS does not send ESME_RINVMSGLEN nack. There are only two possibilities:

- Assuming the SMSC is behaving properly,

  - The SMPP client is sending something wrong and the ESME_RINVMSGLEN is the correct response.
  - You may want to investigate if the client is setting correct value in the command_status field. Depending on command_id, a certain minimum number of bytes may be required.
- Assuming the SMSC is not behaving properly,

  - This may a SMSC specific behavior. You need to consult SMSC documentation at this point.
  - There can be any number of reasons for. It could be that the SMSC reporting ESME_RINVMSGLEN for any other problem it's finding with a PDU.

Comment: HI there I'm manage to disable by changing the code in smpp logica code ... Maybe this is not the right things to do .. but now it's work normally...because I've ask the Operator(client) they want the PDU like that and can't be change, so my last resort is modifying smpp logica library,thank's for your answer :)